# Getting 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Workbooks' when working with Interop.Excel

Tags: c#

Built this program like in the last 3 months. It is just a desktop app they wanted to read through and Excel file and build some SQL with the data.  Was working fine and another team added to it to get some data they needed.  I moved to a new team and haven't opened this project for like a month. Since I know how it works, I was asked to add a piece to the program and when I opened it, the Interop.Office part I was using to open and go through the Excel is now giving me errors.  The two errors are 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Workbooks' and 'Workbook' does not contain a definition for 'Sheets'.  I have gone through what has been changed in the program and nothing should have effected this.  I even went into branches that I know were working when I last opened it and they don't work as well.

The code where the errors come in is here:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();  
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

The errors are on the second and third lines.

The using statement is this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I have spent a day and a half searching for an answer without avail. The package is currently a COM reference but I did add it as a project reference instead and that caused a bunch of different errors so I went back to the COM reference.  I did have some work security updates since I have last worked on this but I don't know what they were to know if they could even possibly effect this.

Comment: Workbook and Workbooks are different.  Make sure you are consistent.  Second line should be Excel.Worbooks

Comment: That is not the issue.  It is Workbook and Workbooks on purpose.  First one is that I am creating a single Workbook object and the second is because I am looking through the collection of Workbooks on that Application.  Thanks for the thought though, I wish it was that simple.

Comment: The 's' doesn't mean you have more than one object.  Workbook and Workbooks are two different objects with different properties.

Comment: Ok but every tutorial or example you look up has it going this way. I do not know enough to argue the details of it, I just know it worked like this last month and is not now.

Comment: Maybe Microsoft fixed a bug.  I've been working with programming excel for at least 25 years and seen the same error when I mix up workbook and workbooks.  Did you change the version of the Interop?  Did you update your Microsoft Office version?