I am using C# to display results in Excel. Its showing Compile Error CS1061
Code will open a new Excel file (visible = False) and data will be entered then the Excel file will be made visible (visible = True).
using oExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    excelApp = new oExcel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excelApp.AskToUpdateLinks = false;
    wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
    ws = wb.Sheets[1];
}

It's showing error on Visible, DisplayAlerts, AskToUpdateLinks and Workbooks.
Error is as follows:

Error CS1061
'Application' does not contain a definition for 'AskToUpdateLinks' and no accessible extension method 'AskToUpdateLinks' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787727/11683

Compiler Error CS1061 : This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist. Check the reference to Excel, if Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is referenced correctly and check how the varaible excelApp is declared, it needs to be of the type oExcel.Application.
